# What's the best way to set all values of a three-dimensional array to zero in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a three-dimensional array that I want to reset to zero.  It seems that there should be an easy way to do this that doesn't involve three `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            cube[i][j][k] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my braces won't line up, you get the point.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a three dimensional array?

Comment: Switch to using a 1D array of n*n*n size, and wrap it in a class with method set(int i, int j, int k) and get(...) etc that does the maths to access values within as if it was a 3D array. Stick a clear() method on there too, with only one for loop inside! You could also use Arrays.fill for the inner loop if you keep the 3D array.

Comment: yes three dimensional.  Fixed.

Comment: It isn't a three-dimensional array, folks.  It is a 2-dimensional array with 3 columns.

Comment: If it is a 3-dimensional array, what is the third dimension?  If you were to add a fourth column would that be a 4-dimensional array?  A 3-dimensional object has length, width, and *depth*.  Your array only has length and width.

Comment: Goodness gracious - please stop changing this!  This is not a 3-dimensional array!

Comment: The question, as it stands now, references a 3-dimensional array - at least the code for clearing the array is for one.

Comment: I was completely and utterly wrong here - the OP was 100% correct to call this array 3-dimensional.  I have edited to fix my idiotic roll-backs and officially apologize for my mistake.  Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Meaning_of_dimension.

Comment: If any reader is interested in performance, you'll want to know that using new to allocate a new array is much slower than using a loop to zero out an existing array.  See my [blog post](http://closms.blogspot.ca/2012/06/efficiently-zero-multidimensional-array.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using JDK 1.5 or higher:

```
    for (int[][] square : cube) {
        for (int[] line : square) {
            Arrays.fill(line, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: not necessarily a cube or a square but still, great naming indeed.

Answer (score 14):

An array will be filled with zeros after initialization:

```
int[][][] cube = new int[10][20][30];
```

This you can do also later, to reset them array to zero, it is not limited to declaration:

```
cube = new int[10][20][30];
```

Simply create a new array, it is initialized with zeros. This works if you have one place that is holding the reference to the array. Don't care about the old array, that will be garbage collected.

If you don't want to depend on this behavior of the language or you can't replace all occurrences of references to the old array, than you should go with the [Arrays.fill()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int[],%20int)) as jjnguy mentioned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < cube[i].length; j++)
   {
      Arrays.fill(cube[i][j], 0);
   }
}
```

Arrays.fill seems to use a loop in the inside too, but it looks generally more elegant.

Comment: Thanks.  The point is that I need to reset to zero after obtaining nonzero values.

Comment: then just declare a new array, the old one will be garbage collected if there's nothing referencing it

Answer (score 13):

Well, it seems that you could just abandon the old array and create a new one:

```
int size = 10;
cube = new int[size][size][size];
```

Comment: only works if you don't have a reference to the (old) array elsewhere

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length){
        Arrays.fill(arr[i][j], 0);
    }
}
```

That way you get rid of one extra loop using [Arrays.fill](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(double[],%20double));

Or

```
arr = new double[arr.length][arr[0].length][arr[0][0].length];
```

Unfortunately, this assumes the array is at least `length >= 1`.

Comment: Doesn't fill() just do the same thing anyway?

Comment: Yeah, it really isn't a whole lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that that *is* a 3D array, the most readable solution is often the best (best is a subjective word, you should have said best in terms of some property, and readability is usually my first choice).

If there were really only three elements in the inner loop and you wanted to emphasize that there were three columns, you could try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
        cube[i][j][0] = 0; 
        cube[i][j][1] = 0; 
        cube[i][j][2] = 0; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always do this:

```
Arrays.fill(cube[0][0],0);
Arrays.fill(cube[0],cube[0][0]);
Arrays.fill(cube,cube[0]);
```

It's a little cleaner than 3 loops.

If you don't get the idea, the first "fill" fills a single dimension. The second fill copies that one dimension across two dimension. The third fill copies the two dimensions across three dimensions.

If you don't have other references to the array that you need to preserve, re-creating it as others have suggested is probably faster and cleaner.

Comment: That sure is not a good ideia. You are putting the same array (object) from cube[0][0] into cube[0][1], cube[0][2]..., and then putting the same array from cube[0] into cube[1], cube[2]...
if you, for example, changes cube[0][1][2] to 1, cube[1][1][2], cube[0][0][2],... will get the same 1!

Answer (score 1):

If all the rows are the same length you could just discard the array and build a new one since the default value of int elements is zero.

```
cube = new int[cube.length][cube[0].length][cube[0][0].length];
```

Or you could do

```
for(int[][] tda : cube ) {
  for(int[] oda : tda) {
    java.util.Arrays.fill(oda, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new array and assign the variable to it... The GC will clean up the old array